# Draw and save graphics to IndexedDB / Local Storage using ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, offline, graphics

I need to add graphics to a map with class.

Is it any sample or way to save it to IndexedDB or Local Storage ?

I tried to use offline-editor-js but this library don´t offer possibility to save graphics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require([
        "esri/map", 
        "esri/toolbars/draw",
        "esri/layers/GraphicsLayer", 
        "esri/symbols/SimpleFillSymbol", 
        "esri/graphic", 
        "dojo/domReady!"
      ], function(
        Map, Draw,
        GraphicsLayer, SimpleFillSymbol, 
        Graphic
      ) {
        map = new Map("mapDiv", {
          basemap: "streets",
          center: [-25.312, 34.307],
          zoom: 3
        });

        var tempLayer = new GraphicsLayer();
        map.addLayer(tempLayer)
        if(localStorage.features != undefined){
        JSON.parse(localStorage.features).forEach(function(featureJson){
        tempLayer.add(new Graphic(featureJson));
        })
        }

        var tool = new Draw(map);
        tool.on("draw-end",function(evt){
        var graphic= new Graphic(evt.geometry,new SimpleFillSymbol());
        tempLayer.add(graphic)
        var graphics =[];
        if(localStorage.features != undefined){
        graphics = JSON.parse(localStorage.features)
        }
        graphics.push(graphic.toJson());
        localStorage.features=JSON.stringify(graphics);
        })
        tool.activate(Draw.POLYGON)




      });
```